# DrawerOpened event handler is note invoked in Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I use DrawerLayout widget in Monodroid, ported from this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html.

The drawer works fine, however the DrawerOpened and DrawerClosed event handler is never invoked when the drawer is either opened or closed. I use the built-in listener from the widget. The drawer layout is placed in fragment.

Any idea? Help is greatly appreciated.

```
this.DrawerLayout.DrawerClosed += delegate(object sender,   Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Activity.ActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.ApplicationName);
            this.Activity.InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };

            this.DrawerLayout.DrawerOpened += delegate(object sender, Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerOpenedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Activity.ActionBar.SetTitle(this.Title);
            this.Activity.InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };

        this.DrawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(this.DrawerToggle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just come across this problem myself. I believe this event is fired if you set the drawer listener before setting the delegates for the Drawer Opened and Closed events.

So just change your code to this:

```
this.DrawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(this.DrawerToggle);

this.DrawerLayout.DrawerClosed += delegate(object sender,   Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Activity.ActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.ApplicationName);
            this.Activity.InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };

            this.DrawerLayout.DrawerOpened += delegate(object sender, Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerOpenedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Activity.ActionBar.SetTitle(this.Title);
            this.Activity.InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };
```

This seemed to work for me.